# com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException

Tags: java, mule

I am getting this exception while converting from xml to object.
"cardHolder (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException)"
My class is given below:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CardHolder {
    String transactionType;
    String cardNumber;

    //cons..
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Please post full stacktrace and also the xml you are trying to parse with XStream

Comment: Exception stack is:
1. CardHolder (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException)
  com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper:56 (null)
2. CardHolder (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException)
  org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer:139 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerMessagingException.html)

Comment: <flow name="resttransformer" doc:name="resttransformer">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
            <component class="org.example.RestClass"/>
         </jersey:resources>
        <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer doc:name="XML to Object"/>
    </flow>
</mule>

Comment: Well this does in no way match your CardHolder class. So it is not surprising it cannot convert between the two.
Maybe have a look at the XStream tutorial: http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html for examples of how this works and how you can configure XStream

Answer (score 0):

In order to transform the Jersey response you need to extract the entity as it is wrapped by a MuleResponseWriter.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Jersey+Module+Reference

From the doc:
    ContainerResponse cr = (ContainerResponse)
    message.getInvocationProperty("jersey_response");
    String messageString = (String) cr.getResponse().getEntity();
    message.setPayload(messageString);

You could create a custom transformer with this in or you can create a simple script transformer similar to the following and place it before your xml-to-object transformer:

```
  <!-- Should be MuleResponseWriter -->
    <logger level="INFO" message="Payload after jersey resource: #[payload]" />
    <scripting:transformer>
        <scripting:script engine="groovy">
            <scripting:text><![CDATA[
        import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;

        ContainerResponse cr = (ContainerResponse)flowVars['jersey_response'];
        message.setPayload(cr.getResponse().getEntity()); 
        ]]></scripting:text>
        </scripting:script>
    </scripting:transformer>
<!-- What type? -->
<logger level="INFO" message="Payload after script: #[payload]" />
```

Comment: Jersey response is in XML.

Comment: To the client yes. But within a Mule flow after jersey:resources it will be wrapped in a MuleResponseWriter. Can you place a logger after the jersey resources tag - <logger level="INFO" message="From jersey resource: #[payload]" /> This should show you the payload type.

Comment: It is showing: INFO  2013-08-21 17:59:12,756 [[resttransformer_Test].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: From jersey resource: org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter$1@141a32f

Comment: Yep so you need to use the above code snippet or similar to convert org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter to the xml you were expecting so you can run the xml-object transformer on it.

Comment: Hi Ryan Carter, I have placed the script in xml.flow above to xml-object converter. After that I am getting the ": only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1)  (com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException). Message payload is of type: String". I am new to this so kindly guide me..

Comment: Apologies I assumed the return type of the jersey component was an XML String. What type are you returning from your jersey method? a POJO? If so don't cast cr.getResponse().getEntity() to a String. Also if it is a POJO, do you need to use the xml-object-transformer at all? Also if you could log the payload again after the script I might be able to help a bit more.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for your kind support. I am providing the service class which is returning POJO. @Path("restClass")
public class RestClass {
 @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/hello")
  public CardHolder getExample()
  {
  CardHolder cardHolder = new CardHolder("Debit", "1002");
  
  return cardHolder;
  }
 
}

Comment: @XmlRootElement(name="CardHolder")
public class CardHolder {
 String transactionType;
 String cardNumber;
 
 public CardHolder() {
 }
 //Constructor
 @XmlElement(name="TransactionType")
 public String getTransactionType() {
  return transactionType;
 }
 @XmlElement(name="CardNumber")
 public String getCardNumber() {
  return cardNumber;
 }
 //setters
}

Comment: This question is getting a bit too long now. First of all, what is it you are trying to do? You don't need the xml-object because at that point of your flow -  your payload should be an instance of your Cardholder class.

Comment: I am trying to take Rest Service response i.e. xml response of Cardholder and trying to convert that xml response into json. In order to convert from xml to json there is no transformer in mule. So what I thought is to convert xml to object and then into object to json. Thats what I was trying to do.

Comment: Ok. So you don't need to convert xml to object because it is already an object after your jersey resource(as far as your Mule flow is concerned) So after you have unwrapped the CardHolder class from the MuleResponseWriter(using the script above but remove the cast to a String) use the instructions here for converting to json: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Native+Support+for+JSON

Comment: My service class is producing @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML), so the CardHolder object will be converted to XML and returned from the service. That XML response of CardHolder I want to convert into JSON.

Comment: I understand that. Place a logger after the script to show you what type of payload you need to work with and go from there. Don't cast it to a String and just log the payload.

Comment: Try the amended code in my answer to see what type you need to transform.